# Custom tags sorting in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I have this in Woocommerce single product pages. I want to change the display of tags under different categories. I want to sort the tags under different custom categories. Example:

Material: Gold, Silver, Rose Gold 
Chain: 16" Chain, 20" Chiain

[image: example]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear as you use confusing words… In woocommerce there is different custom taxonomies: 1) Product categories, 2) Product Tags, 3) Product attributes (each product attribute is a custom taxonomy and can have multiple values. Some of them can be used as attribute for variations in variable products.)… Also, there is Dimensions and Weight (meta data). So may be you should reword your question.

Comment: what I mean is that can I sort the product tags? Like I have tags gold, silver, 16" chain, blue, metal...and then when they are displayed on product tags they will be sorted according to what I want?

Comment: Please edit your question rewording it, and try to make it clear, to have any chances to get useful answers.